# POST method not allowed 405

Tags: django, heroku, post

'Add item' not working, symptom: 'POST method not allowed 405'. it is using 'create view'. 'add category' which bases on same class view works fine.

the error hasn't occur since I uploaded 2 weeks ago on Heroku, there is no use if I roll back to the point it is less complex and working.

i don't know what makes the app fail without changing code

**add item works fine only in 2 categories 'hello-xinxin','songs life',i guess this means the code is good. other categories can't not be added in any new item. is this because database mess up?**

- The app: http://songs-todolist.herokuapp.com/todolist/
- Source code: https://github.com/SongGithub/2DoList

Answer (score 0):

The url you are trying to access is not mentioned in your urls.py of to_do_list_app.

That's why, it is failing.

Comment: thanks for reply, BUT why it works fine locally, while fails on Heroku?

Comment: Please check the source code that you're running on the local machine.

Comment: Mark it as accepted if this answer helped you. So that, other users can come to know that this question is already answered.